# PHP mail function not working

Tags: forms, session, session-variables, php

I do not think the problem lies with the mail function code, but with my aproach of the $_SESSION variables. I have a form consisting of 5 pages, the fifth being a preview page. Upon the final submission, on the preview page, i want the entire $_SESSION data to be sent to two different email adresses.

I am displaying the data on the preview page as follows:

```
<?php
//retrieve session data
echo "<b>&nbsp;&nbsp;Varname: </b>". $_SESSION['varname'];
?>
```

in a form with method="post" and action="mail.php".

In the mail.php, i start the session, and then:

```
    $_SESSION['email'] = $mail;
        $_SESSION['varname'] = $varname;

        $email_from = 'mail@company.de';

        $email_subject = "Mail";

        $email_body = "You have submitted the following data: $inhalt.\n";

        $to = "mymail@company.de, $mail";

        $headers = "From: Company";




        mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
```

Upon submitting the form the page goes to blank. What exactly am i doing wrong?

Comment: Are the missing semi-colons on the two lines with `$_SESSION` typos? Actually, there's one missing on the `$email_body` line, too.

Comment: Have you tried just plain `mail` to make sure the system supports it?

Comment: And what error do you get? None, maybe your server isn't setup correctly to send email.

Comment: I corrected the typos. I am going to try out the function and be back with feedback.

Comment: Also try to turn on error reporting when you are developing, makes finding errors a lot easier. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: also why you defined email_from, but then you don't use it? also varname seems unddefined, but maybe you have it defined before that code.

Comment: where is $mail and $varname coming from? should these be $_POST['mail']? also try it without headers first, then double check additional_headers and \r\n http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: You say the page is going blank, but are the emails going through?  Is that the full mail.php script?

Comment: mail () is supported by the server, however the mails are not going through. The page is still going blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem in the end, as follows:

```
   $email_from = 'mail@company.de';

   $email_subject = "Mail"; 

   $to = ("myadress@work.de," . $_SESSION['email'] . "");
        mail($to,"Form submission","Form data:

    Inhalt: " . $_SESSION['inhalt1'] . " 

    ");
```

As I said in the question, the problem was my aproach of the `$_SESSION` variables. Instead of `$_SESSION['varname'] = $varname`, i just went directly with `. $_SESSION['varname'] .`´.